# Exit csh script based on previous error code

Tags: python, csh, exit-code

I have a shell script running a python script. In the event of a non-zero exit code I would like the exit the current csh script. The example code below in the csh script does not seem to be working.

```
./pythonfile.py
if $? != 0 then
    echo 'Something went wrong!' $?
    exit 1
endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most `csh` versions are actually `tcsh`. In `tcsh`, *both* `$?` and `$status` should work. Looking at the `Fixes` file, it seems this has been the case since 1992...

The problem in your code, is that the `if` statement will override the value of the `$status`/`$?` variables; you need to use an intermediate variable to store the exit code.

```
false
set code = $?
if $code != 0 then
    echo 'Something went wrong! ' $code
    exit 1
endif
```